# Rustからshell関数を使いたい

Tags: shellscript, rust

#### 目標

Rustからshell関数を使う

#### 何を知りたいか

- Rustから`Command::new()`で[`ls`を実行するみたいに](https://qiita.com/Kumassy/items/3fb3e52729e375efd5ed)shellの関数を呼び出す方法
- 出来ないのであれば別の方法
- 不可能であればその理由

#### 試したこと

- shell関数`_foo`を作って`~/.bashrc`に登録。
  ターミナルから`_foo`が使えることを確認。
  `Command::new("_foo").output()`を実行すると、`No such file or directory`と表示される。
- `Command::new("bash")`で色々やってみたがよく分からなかった。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~/.bashrc`はシェルを対話的に実行するときに読み込まれるものなので、`bash -c`でコマンドを非対話的に実行する時には読み込まれません。

目的の関数を呼ぶ前に`~/.bashrc`を読み込んでやれば動くと思います。

```rust
let output = std::process::Command::new("bash")
    .args(&["-c", "source ~/.bashrc && _foo"])
    .output()
    .expect("failed to run command");

println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
println!("stderr: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr));
```